# groovy.langMissingMethodException in calling groovy function

Tags: grails

I have a Grails `GSP page` similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var currency = ${Currency.getList() as JSON};
        </script>
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

And a `groovy` file similar to this:

```
package enums
import java.util.List;

public final class Currency {
    private static final List CURRENCIES =  ['PHP','USD','HKD'];
    static List getList(){
        return CURRENCIES
    }
}
```

Now it shows an `error` message:

**groovy.lang.MissingMethodException**

> No signature of method: static java.util.Currency.getList() is
>   applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions:
>   getAt(java.lang.String), getClass(), split(groovy.lang.Closure),
>   notify(), wait()

How can I resolve this? The `groovy` file is placed in `project/src` directory, and is not allowed to move (if that helps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message **you are using a different `Currency` class** from `java.util` package.

---

So try using your own class which is `enums.Currency.getList()` rather than `java.util.Currencty.getList()`.

---

update:

Also import JSON class. According to your comments it seems my answer is not clear for you. So your code will be like this:

```
package enums
import java.util.List;
import grails.converters.JSON;

public final class Currency {
    private static final List CURRENCIES =  ['PHP','USD','HKD'];
    static List getList(){
        return CURRENCIES
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows a different error: `startup failed: <c:/......>: 35: unable to resolve class JSON @ line XX, column XXX. .enums.Currency.getList() as JSON }) ^ 1 error`

Comment: Where should I supposed to put the `import` statement in the `gsp`?

Comment: no, import it on the currency that where you are using it.

Comment: something like `<%@ page import="myapp.MyClass" %>` can be used to add import to the gsp. Or again use the fully qualified class name

Answer (score 1):

Since you call the static groovy function from inside your HTML, I suspect you need to add the modifier "public" to your static method so:

```
public static List getList()
```

EDIT: Above is not the issue, but the exception complains about the class Currency from the java.util package, not from your own package "enums".

Comment: I've also use the `public` modifier, nothing happens, the same `error` message displays.

Comment: Ok, I have read the error better, it states:  java.util.Currency, So it is looking at java.util, instead of your enum package. You should make sure it imports your class, or fully qualify it in the code.

Comment: Just for completeness: `public` is the default visibility modifier in Groovy. So it is as the edit states, not the error, but the wrong Currency class, which comes in through a default import. Unlike java we do not only import java.lang automatically.  That problem can be solved by either using explicit import, or by using the fully qualified package names, just like in Java.

Comment: @blackdrag, I used this code but still throws the same `error` message: `var currency = ${enums.Currency.getList() as JSON}`. Does it have no issue if the `groovy` file is places inside the `src` directory?

Comment: my comment was on what was there before the edit. Also I understood it is not complaining about Currency now anymore